# Relating solution to non-homogenous system and homogenous one

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose the solution to the system $A\textbf{x} = \textbf{b}$ is a line. Does the corresponding homogeneous system have nonzero solutions?

I think the answer is yes. If the solution to the non-homogeneous system is a line, $\textbf{x} = \textbf{p} + t\textbf{v}$ then that implies that the system must have one free variable. Then the corresponding homogeneous system must also have one free variable and so it cannot only have the trivial solution.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. The solutions of the homogeneous and inhomogeneous system differ by a vector. If the solution of the inhomogeneous system is a line, the one for the homogeneous system is a parallel line through the origin, so it has non-zero solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that for two non-zero vectors $\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2}$ where $\mathbf{x_1} \neq \mathbf{x_2}$ that $A\mathbf{x_1} = \mathbf{b}$ and $A\mathbf{x_2} = \mathbf{b}$. Then 
\begin{align*}
A\mathbf{x_1} -A\mathbf{x_2} &= \mathbf{b} - \mathbf{b} \\
A(\mathbf{x_1}-\mathbf{x_2}) &= \mathbf{0}
\end{align*}
Because $\mathbf{x_1} \neq \mathbf{x_2}$, it follows that $\mathbf{x_1}-\mathbf{x_2} \neq \mathbf{0}$, meaning that there exists nonzero solutions to the corresponding homogeneous system.

Comment: Another approach here to your question.